# LTSP thin client - Mount local hard drive

Tags: ltsp, ltsp-client

If I am running a thin client on an LTSP server, is there any way to mount the client local hard drive ?

I know the system is not running *on* the client, but as I can use removable devices (USB sticks, CD/DVD), can't I use the local drive ?

Thanks for answering !

Comment: Tried `mount /dev/sdx /mnt/sdx`?

Comment: Yes.
As the system does not run on the client, I cannot see the local drive, even using `fdisk` or `blkid`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the options `LOCALDEV = true` and `LOCALDEV_DENY_INTERNAL_DISKS = false` in your lts.conf which you will usually find under /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/"arch"/lts.conf. Replace "arch" with the client architecture you want to modify (in most cases one of i386 or amd64). See also http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/Devices